# Select if different from string sql

Tags: mysql

I have a web app where users can fill forms and results are registered into a MySQL DB.
Here is the DB : `USERS(id,name,email,extras)`

If users use form #1, id, name and email are filled in DB.
If users use form #2, id and extras are filled in DB.

So I have a table like :

```
1 | John      | john@john.com     | 

2 | Johnny    | johnny@johnny.com | 

3 | undefined | undefined         | "name: Dumbo, email: dumbo@dumbo.fr"
```

I'd like to extract name and email from all rows where extras is empty : this query is okay.
I'd like to extract extras from rows where name and email are undefined. And combine these queries.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "undefined"?  Null?

Comment: No, a string 'undefined' is written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM USERS 
WHERE COALESCE(extras) = '' OR 
(name = 'undefined' AND email = 'undefined');
```

Comment: Ok thanks. And is it possible to select only extras when email and name = 'undefined' ? And select only name, email when extras is empty.

Comment: They would need to be different SELECTs since you are asking for different columns in a single SELECT.

Comment: Ok thanks for your advice, I'll try something based on your query